# How to register Castle DynamicProxy Interceptor with Typed Client in C#?

Tags: c#, microservices, abp, castle-dynamicproxy

I have created a HttpClient for "DemoMicroService" with Typed Client through IHttpClientFactory.
I want to use an interceptor "DemoMicroInterceptor" defined by Castle DynamicProxy to intercept all methods call details (whenever methods 1 & 2 are called by the application service or other microservices) in "DemoMicroService".

How to register Castle DynamicProxy Interceptor with Typed Client in C#?

"DemoMicroService.cs":

```
    public class DemoMicroService: IDemoMicroService
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

        public DemoMicroService(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            _httpClient = httpClient;
        }

        public async Task<XXXDto> Method1(int abc)
        {
            //Method1 Implementation
        }
        public async Task<XXXDto> Method2(int edf)
        {
            //Method2 Implementation
        }
    }
```

"DemoMicroInterceptor.cs":

```
    public class DemoMicroInterceptor: IInterceptor
    {
        public DemoMicroInterceptor()
        {
        }

        public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
        {
            // Log the method name and input parameters
            var methodName = invocation.Method.Name;
            var inputParams = string.Join(",", invocation.Arguments.Select(a => a.ToString()));
            Debug.WriteLine($"Calling method {methodName} with parameters: {inputParams}");

            // Invoke the original method
            invocation.Proceed();

            // Log the return value
            var returnValue = invocation.ReturnValue;
            Debug.WriteLine($"Method {methodName} returned: {returnValue}");
        }
    }
```

Typed Client is defined under "HttpApiHostModule.cs":

```
 private void ConfigureHttpClient(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
    {
        context.Services.AddHttpClient<DummyJsonService>(httpClient =>
        {
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://dummyjson.com/");
        });
    }
```

I know the current configuration in "HttpApiHostModule.cs" can not make the interceptor recognize which microservice should be intercepted. But I have searched online and no similar approach is found.

I have also followed the code in "https://gist.github.com/tiagocesar/c5c65d91e1d609e361c347350e26521c", which fails.

Comment: I'm having the same problem as you've described here, just wondering did you find any workaround for that